# How do I change the font and size of a hyperlink inserted into ms word with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have a subroutine in ms access that runs this line of code

wrdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wrdDoc.Bookmarks("LCEmail").Range, Address:="abc@yahoo.com"

How do I change the font of the inserted email to Microsoft sans serif and the font size to 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can;

```
With wrdDoc.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=wrdDoc.Bookmarks("LCEmail").Range, Address:="abc@yahoo.com")
    .Range.Font.Name = "Microsoft sans serif"
    .Range.Font.Size = 10
End With
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will not have to pull my hair out now.